A book (soft sci-fi) about cloned religious Saints from their relics. These newly cloned kids are studied by a scientist who is the narrator
The narrator should be a woman, who is a scientist/neurologist/developmental psychologist has some kind of cancer(?). She ("I") took on this research project and get to know these children and study them. Then later found out that they are clones or somehow reproduced from religious Saint relics. I might have read the Chinese or English version of this book in 2010s or early 2020s? Really would hope to find this out!

Welcome! Can you recall how her having cancer fit in the plot? What country did the story occur? What happened after she discovered that the children were clones? Any details might help. Sounds intriguing.

I solved this one myself. It's All Saints Mountain by  Olgo Tokarczuk.

I asked about the children we were to study: who were they, why were
they to undergo the test, what was the purpose of our program? Though
I also knew it wasn't any of my business.

I thought it was a novel, but it's actually a 12,000 word short story.

You should click the checkmark next to this answer to mark it as accepted since you have answered your own question!
